# How to output a different help text depending on the outer subcommand?

Tags: rust, struct, clap

I am making a Rust CLI program that uses Clap to parse arguments.

I made something like this.

```
#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum SubType {
    /// Operate on entries
    Operate(Entries),

    /// Generate entries
    Generate(Entries)
}

#[derive(Args)]
pub struct Entries {
    /// Hint for this <-- Label that I want to show differently for both generate and operate
    #[arg(value_parser)]
    pub entries: Vec<String>
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just make two different `OperationEntries` and `GenerateEntries` structs with different comments? You can use macros to duplicate the rest of the fields if required.